# Using Vert.x handle errors thrown in request middleware

Tags: java, vert.x

Say I have some middleware and an error is raised:

```
public class JWTHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {

  public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
    throw new Error("How can I capture this error and send a response.")
    ctx.next();
  }
}
```

How can I capture it using some error-handling middleware? Here is a global error handler but it can't reference any request/response pair.

```
vertx.createHttpServer()
  .exceptionHandler(ctx -> {

    // I cannot access the request that may have caused the error here
    log.error("In the exception handler.");
    log.error(ctx.getCause());

  })
```

the only thing I can guess, is something like this:

```
public class ErrorHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {

  public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
    try{
      ctx.next();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       ctx.response().end("We messed up.");
    }
  }
}
```

but I doubt that idea is right? What's the right way to do this?

perhaps one or both of these is sufficient?

```
router.route().failureHandler(ctx -> {
   ctx.response().end("We failed here!");
});

router.route().last().handler(ctx -> {
  ctx.response()
    .setStatusCode(404)
    .end("404 - route/resource could not be found.");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, the correct approach would be to use the `ctx.fail()`, when throwing an exception

```
public class JWTHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
  public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
    ctx.fail(new Error("How can I capture this error and send a response.");
  }
}
```

And then you can add a `failerHandler` and access to the Exception with `ctx.failure()`

```
router.route().failureHandler(ctx -> {
   ctx.response().end(
    ctx.failure().getMessage()
   );
});
```

EDIT:

the failureHandler also catches exceptions that are thrown like you did:

```
public class JWTHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
  public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
    throw new Error("How can I capture this error and send a response.")
    ctx.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: sometimes there is an exception that gets raised that you don't capture/catch, so does Vertx catch it for you? IOW, I won't always be able to call ctx.fail(). Sometimes an error will be raised that isn't from ctx.fail().

Comment: for those cases i suggest to wrap those code blocks around try-catch blocks. You shouldn't rely on default catch methods.

Comment: sure but sometimes we forget to add a try/catch somewhere...catching those errors is the purpose of a framework or what not

Comment: i wasnt sure, i had to try it out, but the failurehandler also gets triggered when you just throw an Exception as you did. So you dont need try-catch blocks.